Facing the "factory runner does not support sending transactions" error while executing deploy script of Hardhat
When I run:
npx hardhat run --network sepolia scripts/deployFlashLoan.js

I am getting this error:
factory runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.12.1)


I am not sure why version is 6.12.1
I want to know the correct way to implement getSigner() to solve this problem.

Ethers version in package.json "ethers": "^5.1.3",
and I installed ethers with:
npm i ethers@5.1.3

deployFlashLoan.js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("dotenv").config();
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  
        const account = await ethers.getSigners()

        const FlashLoan = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("FlashLoan");

        const flashLoan = await FlashLoan.deploy("0x012bAC54348C0E635dCAc9D5FB99f06F24136C9A");
   
        await flashLoan.waitForDeployment();

}
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error("Hello5"+error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});

.env
PRIVATE_KEY="0xMetamask Account"        
SEPOLIA_RPC_URL="https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/<APIKEY>"

hardhat.config.js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");
require("dotenv").config();
require('hardhat-deploy');

module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    sepolia: {
      url: process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
      account: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.25"
      },
      {
        version: "0.8.10"
      }
    ],
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 40000
  }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "hardhat-project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/abi": "^5.7.0",
    "@ethersproject/providers": "^5.7.1",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.6",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.2",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.0",
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.5.1",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.3",
    "hardhat": "^2.22.3",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.12.4",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.2",
    "typechain": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aave/core-v3": "^1.16.2",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.6",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.7.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2"
  },
  "description": "This project demonstrates a basic Hardhat use case. It comes with a sample contract, a test for that contract, and a script that deploys that contract.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "hardhat.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Thanks.

Please add the deployment script that you’re using.

Instead of adding in the comments, it would be much better if you add it in your question by editing the same. As, here, it’s hardly readable.

thanks Syed, I have edited the question.

In your hardhat.config.js file, inside the sepolia object of networks, it should be accounts instead of account , like:
sepolia: {
    url: process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
    accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
}

Also, you don't have to use the ethers library explicitly, as the deployment would be handled by the hardhat itself when using hre.ethers.
So, you can just uninstall ethers:
npm uninstall ethers@5.1.3

The revised deployment script should be:
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

    const FlashLoan = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("FlashLoan");

    const flashLoan = await FlashLoan.deploy("0x012bAC54348C0E635dCAc9D5FB99f06F24136C9A");

    await flashLoan.waitForDeployment();

    console.log("FlashLoan is deployed at address:", await flashLoan.getAddress())

}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error("Hello5" + error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});


change Account to Accounts - Invalid account: #0 for network: sepolia - private key too short, expected 32 bytes.          Other errors going off.
If I keep Account
HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received: invalid project id  const FlashLoan = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("FlashLoan");

I think you're using the wallet address instead of private key in your .env file. You can export the private key of your MetaMask account and then use the same in the value of PRIVATE_KEY in your .env file.

hi Syed,   thanks for your help. solved the problem.                                                      as you said was using Wallet address instead of Private key.

Great. You're welcome, Uday. Happy coding!
